# Visual studio: How-to pass string argument to exe using post build script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post-build-event

I'm using visual studio, 
I want to **pass** a file path as a string to an **.exe** using a **post build** script

Currently this is my build script

```
"$(SolutionDir)test" "$(ProjectDir)"
```

But I always get a error saying the command exited with code -532462766

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
$(SolutionDir)test $(ProjectDir)
```

I just needed to remove the quotes in the post script !!!